# Vlookup using calculated field in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, vlookup, calculated-columns, calculated-field

I am new to the `Tableau`
can anyone help me with the below example
I have employees details from agent till managing director in in data Set
`Column A` contains `emp_id` and `column B` contains `Name` of the Employees name and `column C` contains the supervisors `emp_id`.

I want supervisor name in column D which is already available in `column B`. It's like using `vlookup` in excel

```
=vlookup (c1,A:B,2,0)
```

How can use the same logic in tableau

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your data is like

[image]

create a join with itself in tableau something like this

[image]

After this you can you may each empoyee's superviosr name

[image]